# Do proxy in Dart by using noSuchMethod?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have many service classes which simply do the http requests, and I want to count the number of currently running http requests. My naive idea is to use a proxy like -

```
int currentRunHttpRequestCounter = 0;

class MyProxy {
  noSuchMethod() {
    currentRunHttpRequestCounter+=1;
    magically_call_the_original_class(...);
    currentRunHttpRequestCounter-=1;
  }
}
```

However, I do not know how to `magically_call_the_original_class`? In other words, how do I create a proxy that passes every method call down to the original class?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create one abstract HTTP service with static counter.
inside that abstract service use counter and logging inside your HTTP methods.

Then extend that service into mocked or real service, and every time you call it it will update the counter.

```dart
class Counter {
  var getCount = 0;
}

abstract class HttpService {
  static Counter counter = Counter();
  
  Future<dynamic> get(Map<String, dynamic> query) {
    counter.getCount++;
    // use for logging ect
  }
}

class HttpMockedService extends HttpService {
  @override
  Future get(Map<String, dynamic> query) {
    // TODO: implement get
    super.get(query);
  }
}

class HttpRealService extends HttpService {
  @override
  Future get(Map<String, dynamic> query) {
    // TODO: implement get
    super.get(query);
  }
}
```

This is simplified solution, but you can play with many approaches to it.

Comment: Good idea, thanks! However, I am making some fake http calls which directly returns data, so they actually do not call an "actual" HttpService... Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have both fake and real http, or do you have only fake for now, that you will switch with real one later

Comment: both fake and real

Comment: Then you need to create abstract http service. Implement real one and fake one. Then create counter singleton, and provide it to both real and fake one. So you will have one place where you count. What architecture do you use, so I can write an answer. Provider? Bloc? Singletons?

Comment: Or create static counter on abstract class, and call that counter everytime

Comment: So you mean I still need to call the counter in each and every method implementation? I am using mobx + GetIt. Anyway thanks!

Comment: not in every method, I will update the answer later today